# Can I use MSAL to develop client side implementation of OIDC with an IDP that is built with neither Azure nor any Microsoft technology?

Tags: openid-connect, azure-ad-msal

Can I use MSAL (ASP.NET Core Microsoft Authentication Library) to develop the client-side implementation of OIDC with an IDP that is built with neither Azure nor any Microsoft technology? Microsoft documentation does not say it specifically, but I wonder these being open standards should work across the implementations.